# why the following code gives runtime error

Tags: c++

```
map <char,int> m;

map <char, int> :: iterator pos;

int main()

{

int t,n,i,max;
string str;
cin>>t;   // testcase
while(t--)
{
    max=1;
    cin>>n;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        m[str[i]]=0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>str[i];
        m[str[i]]=m[str[i]]+1;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(m[str[i]]>max)
        {
            max=m[str[i]];
        }
    }
   cout<<n-max<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Now why is this code gives Runtime error every time when compiled..I compiled using online platform like on ideone.com yet it gives the same error..please help regarding to this

Comment: Think about what `str[i]` does when `str` is empty.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Comment: A runtime error does not happen when code is compiled, it happens when code is ran. Please elaborate and include the details of input and anything else needed to recreate the runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

When you access a character in a string like this:

```
str[i]
```

that string must have length at least `i+1`, you have an empty string.

Comment: sorry to mention it gives runtime error only when n>20

Comment: @SAURAVGUPTA does not matter, your program is invalid even when n == 1